# rosinstall alternative

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is there an alternative to rosinstall?

prince

Edit:

I am sitting behind a proxy in my office. Some of the packages like topological_navigation, deb is not available in diamondback. As per steps mentioned in wiki for this package, rosinstall is required. For installing rosinstall, easy-install look for some pkgs. which it is not able to fetch probably because of proxy. I am looking for wayaround of rosinstall. What all it download. If needed I can do manual fetch and compiles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12854/rosinstall-alternative/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosinstall just goes out and does an svn, git, hg, or bzr checkout of a bunch of source files for you.  You can do it all manually if you want.

However as you clarified your issue is just traversing a proxy, I would simply recommend that you fetch the tarball and install it locally instead of using easy_install or pip.

You can get rosinstall from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rosinstall) and you'll also need vcstools available [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vcstools)

Note: you many have trouble with the checkouts too if you're having trouble getting easy_install to work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-03**:
i copied the souce from other machine, proxy was set using http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyIP:port, it finally got compiled without any failure.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install from debian packages and not use rosinstall to create overlays. You can also just install everything by hand and manage your ros environment variables by hand. Rosinstall is just a helper script that makes keeping repositories up-to-date and managing the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH more convenient.

To give a better answer, it would be good to know what exactly you are looking for, i.e. which features you need? Why do you need an alternative?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1